# border и border-radius

Tags: java, android, xml

Скажем — есть такая разметка:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:shape="rectangle">

<corners android:radius="15px" />

<solid android:color="@color/blackAlpha3" />

<stroke
    android:width="6px"
    android:color="@color/black" />
```

И свою задачу она выполняет. Но, допустим я хочу применить ее к другому элементу, но с другими параметрами и цветами. Вопрос: можно ли поместить эту разметку в переменную, изменить нужные параметры и применить к нужному элементу?

Comment: [тык](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28578701/how-to-create-android-shape-background-programmatically)

Comment: Спасибо. буду пробовать